# Screenshot is not sending to email in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

i've used the code below it was the accepted answer that was given at http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135462/save-screenshot-temporarily-then-retrieve-when-ready

But when the email dialog box opens it shows a  attached file which was screenshot but after sending email there is no attachment in received email.it means screenshot is not sending.

can anyone tell what's wrong in this code???

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // backgroundColor : '#666666'
    backgroundColor : 'red',
    // backgroundImage : 'img/1.jpg'
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : 100,
    height : 30,
    title : 'Test'
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Titanium.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e) {
        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'test.png');
        f.write(e.media);

        var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();
        emailDialog.setToRecipients(['test@gmail.com']);
        emailDialog.setSubject('test');
        emailDialog.setMessageBody('testing......');
        emailDialog.setHtml(true);
        emailDialog.setBarColor('black');
        emailDialog.addAttachment(f.read());

        emailDialog.addEventListener('complete', function(e) {
            if(e.result == emailDialog.SENT) {

                alert("message was sent");

            }
        });
        emailDialog.open();
    });
});

win.add(btn);

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addAttachment` function can take a blob, you don't have to save it to disk. Also, this may not be working because you may not have write access to the `applicationDataDirectory`.

Instead just pass the supplied blob from `e.media` like this:

```
Titanium.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e) {
    var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();
    // Get the supplied blob and attach
    emailDialog.addAttachment(e.media);
    // ...... add other email things here
});
```